# simple array insert in json file

Tags: php, json, file

I have a simple json file.This is the structure.

1 player array which has 1 game and 2 matches array.

I want to add data to matches[0]..first matches array.

I am using matchid attribute which has to store in appropriate match array.

So if my matchid is 4..I want my data to store in matches[0][4].
I tried various combination but cannot get what I want.

Here is my json file,followed by the code I tried.

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "name": "Moldova",
        "image": "/Images/Moldova.jpg",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Georgia",
        "image": "/Images/georgia.gif",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Belarus",
        "image": "/Images/Belarus.gif",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Armenia",
        "image": "/Images/armenia.png",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kazahstan",
        "image": "/Images/kazahstan.gif",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Russia",
        "image": "/Images/russia.gif",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ukraine",
        "image": "/Images/ukraine.png",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Uzbekistan",
        "image": "/Images/uzbekistan.gif",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    }
],
"games": [
    {
        "matches": [
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 1,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 2,
                "player2id": 3,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 4,
                "player2id": 5,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 6,
                "player2id": 7,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 2,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 4,
                "player2id": 6,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 4,
                "winner": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "matches": [
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 1,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 2,
                "player2id": 3,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 4,
                "player2id": 5,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 6,
                "player2id": 7,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 2,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 4,
                "player2id": 6,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 4,
                "winner": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}
And the php code I tried.

```
                    $inp = file_get_contents('jsontrail.json');
        $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
        //adding to the matchid index of matches array
        $matchid=3;
        $arrne['winner'] ="winner";
        $arrne['player1id'] ="player1id";
        $arrne['player2id'] ="player2id";
        array_push($tempArray->games[0]->matches[0]->[$matchid], $arrne );
        $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
        file_put_contents('jsontrail.json', $jsonData);
        print_r( $inp);
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' am getting this error now..

code 2 try

```
                    $inp = file_get_contents('jsontrail.json');

        $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
        //adding to the matchid index of matches array
        $matchid=3;
        $arrne['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['winner'] ="winner";
        $arrne['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['player1id'] ="player1id";
        $arrne['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['player2id'] ="player2id";
        array_push($tempArray,$arrne );
        $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
        file_put_contents('jsontrail.json', $jsonData);
        print_r( $inp);
```

But this push the array to the last..

Comment: are you sure you didn't miss a `$` in front of `arrne = json_decode`?

Comment: oh I left that when posting my code..will edit now..

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius do you have any idea of it..need help..

Comment: No, but I tried to make sure your question is more readable. I switched from php a year ago and I do not have tools to try your code :) Best luck of getting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters your JSON is invalid, there's an extra comma. Copy-paste your json to http://jsonlint.com and it will tell you what's wrong.

And try this code

```
<?php
$arrne = json_decode(file_get_contents('jsontrail.json'),true);
$inp = file_get_contents('jsontrail.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);

//adding to the matchid index of matches array
$matchid = 1;
$newmatch=array();
$newmatch['winner'] ="LOOKFORME";
$newmatch['player1id'] ="player1id";
$newmatch['player2id'] ="player2id";

array_splice($tempArray["games"][0]["matches"], $matchid, 0, array($newmatch));
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('jsontrail.out.json', $jsonData);
```

Comment: I want to add data in playes->games->matches->0->myinputmatchid.. Any idea how I can achieve this??And thanks for replying again

Comment: There is no players->games->matches->0->myinputmatchid, your data is not structured like that.

Comment: Freud..Sorry it is games->matches->0->myinputmatchid..just now checked.. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong:

1) There is a comma on the last match:

```
{
  "player1id":0,
  "player2id":4,
  "winner":0
},
```

Which, for me at least, broke the `json_decode`. I use [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check the format.

2) You get the error `Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type std Class as array` when trying to access `$tempArray['players']['games']['matches'][0]` - the way your JSON is set up, you should be accessing it like this: `$tempArray->games[0]->matches[$matchid]`. However, I think you may need to take another look at the structure of your JSON first.

3) You are passing `` `$tempArray['players']['games']['matches'][0][] `` to `array_push`. If you just meant the first element inside matches, then leave off the `[]`. Check out the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

I'd suggest you take out each seperate step of the script and debug each one in order. For instance, first load the JSON, then dump that to screen. Then decode it and dump that to screen. Then try accessing elements inside it, and dump those to the screen, and so on and so on.

Good luck!

Comment: I suggest editing your original question with the new code so we can see the code changes properly.